# Caliburn micro and xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, caliburn.micro

I am new in xamarin but have used Calibrun Micro on wpf.

I playing with an application that builds by VS 2022

I installed nuget packages for Caliburn.micro.core and caliburn.micro.xamarin.form to all projects.

to test that if it works, I add a button to the AboutView.xaml such as to this one:

```
  <Button Text="test" x:Name="test"/>
```

and also add a function like this to the AboutViewModel class:

```
    public void test()
    {
        int x = 1;
    }
```

I hoped that when I click on the test button, on the "About" page, the test function in AboutViewModel is called, but it doesn't happen.

Reading Caliburn micro documentation, I found that I should install bootstrapper. The documentation of for wpf but I could not find any documentation for Xamarin applications.

My questions are:

1. Is Caliburn micro an active project? is there any replacement for it?
2. Do I need to configure xamarin forms to enable Caliburn micro? if yes, how can I do this?
3. Do I need to install any more packages?

Comment: a quick glance at the nuget page shows that the last stable release for Forms was **4 years** ago.  There is an alpha release that was updated this year.  Based on that I don't think I would rely on it for a production app

Comment: @Jason Thanks, is there any replacement? This page says that it was updated 3 months ago. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Caliburn.Micro.Xamarin.Forms/

Comment: oops, I misread that.  Regardless, a 4 year gap between major releases is not very comforting

Comment: There was a hiatus from the maintainer for some time (due to work and life commitments), but a new team has picked it up to continue building Caliburn.Micro. There is some hope now... 

There is even a plan to have it .net MAUI ready. 

It was my favourite library in my WPF + Windows Phone days, so I am looking to start using it again, but the docs for Xamarin are sorely lacking. Have a look at the samples on their github: https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/tree/master/samples/setup/Setup.Forms <- this is the Xamarin forms specific page.

Comment: I know this is a late response, but a lot of things you can do in WPF with Caliburn.Micro you can't do in Xamarin.Forms. I learned this the hard way. I pretty much went into the GitHub samples and hooked up an empty project using the setup configuration and it worked with some adjustments. The boot strapping is the most important part. You will have to do a lot of the command code yourself. It sucks. I do miss the WPF way of doing things. Maybe one day it will be up to par as WPF.

Comment: I found where they explain about why automatic wired events and auto data-binding does NOT work. It's because there's no programatic access to x:Name. You can read about it here: https://github.com/caliburn-micro/caliburn.micro/releases?page=2 That's a few years old. I'm currently updating my app. I'm going to test to see if the latest versions fixes that. Because on the code behind you can access the names.